# Assign column names to a new empty dataframe from column names of 2 different dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I know this sounds like a repeated question but I searched a lot and couldn't find the answer to this question. Here is my situation.

I have 2 data.frames in R.

1. PotentialTravellersHistory
2. PossibleAirports

The column names of these 2 dataframes are

```
> dput(names(PotentialTravellersHistory))
c("uid", "utc", "lat", "long", "vid")

> dput(names(PossibleAirports))
c("DestinationAirportId", "Airline", "AirlineId", "SourceAirport", 
"SourceAirportId", "DestinationAirport", "Name", "City", "Country", 
"IataFaa", "Icao", "Latitude", "Longitude", "MaxLatitude", "MinLatitude", 
"MaxLongitude", "MinLongitude")
```

My problem is that I need to create a new dataframe "AirportTravellers" which has all the column names as defined above i.e. these column names are combinations of the columns names of first and second dataframe. How do i do that? The example of column names of the "AirportTravellers" is below:

```
"uid", "utc", "lat", "long", "vid", "DestinationAirportId", "Airline",
"AirlineId", "SourceAirport", "SourceAirportId", "DestinationAirport", 
"Name", "City", "Country", "IataFaa", "Icao", "Latitude", "Longitude", 
"MaxLatitude", "MinLatitude", "MaxLongitude", "MinLongitude"
```

Comment: Just use `cbind()`. `AirportTravellers <- cbind(PotentialTravellersHistory, PossibleAirports)`. If you want to combine both the data.frames

Comment: I need to create a new dataframe with the column names of the 2 other dtaframes combined. Just need the names combined and do not need the data in those dataframes combined.

Comment: Alternatively can you tell me how do I create a new empty dataframe whose column names are mentioned above? i.e.
`"uid", "utc", "lat", "long", "vid", "DestinationAirportId", "Airline", "AirlineId", "SourceAirport", "SourceAirportId", "DestinationAirport", "Name", "City", "Country", "IataFaa", "Icao", "Latitude", "Longitude", "MaxLatitude", "MinLatitude", "MaxLongitude", "MinLongitude"`

Comment: Easiest way is `AirportTravellers <- cbind(PotentialTravellersHistory[0,], PossibleAirports[0,])`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton. This did the job. Please add this as an answer so I can accept and get you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is

`AirportTravellers <- cbind(PotentialTravellersHistory[0,], PossibleAirports[0,])`

Answer (score 0):

When only the names are available and there are no already existing data frames :

```
varnames <- c("uid", "utc", "lat", "long", "vid","DestinationAirportId", 
              "Airline","AirlineId", "SourceAirport", "SourceAirportId",
              "DestinationAirport","Name", "City", "Country", "IataFaa",     
              "Icao", "Latitude", "Longitude","MaxLatitude", "MinLatitude", 
              "MaxLongitude", "MinLongitude")
```

Create an empty dataframe:

```
AirportTravellers <- data.frame()
```

Name the variables:

```
for( i in 1:length(varnames)){
     AirportTravellers[0,eval(varnames[i])]
 }
```

Now an empty data frame with the given variable names will be created.